# Comparing hash strings LockBox 3 on Delphi

Tags: delphi, lockbox-3

I am trying to convert an old project which was originally done using TurboPower LockBox 3.7 on Delphi 10 to use TurboPack LockBox 3 2021.11 (from GetIt Package Manager) on Delphi 11.

My orginal code was:

```
Hash1.HashString(edit1.Text);
if Stream_to_Base64(Hash1.HashOutputValue)='AbkShI/vdJjy6jhNAtbcGA==' then
  begin
    // stuff here
  end;
```

where Hash1 is a THash component.

The HashString procedure now has a TEncoding element which was not required before.
Would changing the first line to the following be correct?

```
Hash1.HashString(edit1.Text,TEncoding.Default);
```

More importantly (I think) the second line now gives the error

E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'System.TArray<System.Byte>'

How do I compare the HashOutputValue with an existing string in the new version?